# Can we hide special characters from iPad Keyboard programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I want to hide special characters of iPad keyboard programatically. Is there any way to do this? Or can we display only numeric values on keyboard?

Comment: If u want to prevent users from entering special characters, then you will have to implement it in code via `UITextFieldDelegate`. There is no way to hide keys on iPad keyboard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can not hide the native keyboard any key's or anything tricky or hack. but yes there is some type of keyboard that provide by apple:

[image]

And you can set keyboard type programmatically by following code:

```
 [YourtextFiled setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Comment: Nope actually it show special characters in that.. I want remove that also for iPad.

Comment: we can not do any thing with native control